# A regularity question for elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

> I revise the  question according to the  comment  of  Andrew

Let  $D$  be  an  elliptic  differential operator with analytic  coefficient  on $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, the space of  complex  valued smooth functions  on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let  $A\subset C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2) $ be  the  space of  all real 
 analytic $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{C}$  with a global convergence Taylor series. That is $f$ has a global Taylor series representation(with infinite  radius of  convergence)

Assume  that  $g\in A,\; f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $D(f)=g$  does this  imply that  $f\in A$?

I  am  aware of the  following  regularity  property  but I  am not sure this would  answer my question(regarding the infinite radius Taylor  expansion):

**Regularity:**  If $g$ is  real  analytic then $f$ is  real  analytic.

The  motivation for this  question  is  coming from the  following post:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304019/the-comparison-of-certain-modules-arising-from-the-cauchy-riemann-differential-o

Comment: An elliptic operator can have not analytic coefficients and in this case the statement doesn't hold.

Comment: This is not a question about elliptic regularity, it is only about the radius of convergence of analytic functions. It is a known fact that the radius of convergence of a real-analytic function is as big ``as it can be'', that is, it is such that any singularity is in the border of the disc of convergence.

Comment: What I claimed above is false. Consider the function $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2 +1) + 1/(y^2 +1)$. This function is real-analytic on the entire $R^2$ but the radius of convergence obviously is not infinity.

Comment: If you take the operator $D$ as being the Laplacian multiplied $(x^2+1)^3(y^2 + 1)$ and apply it to the function $f$ defined above, don't you get an analytic function $g$ of infinite radius of convergence?

Comment: @MaxReinholdJahnke  Your idea is very interesting. If you  write  an  answer  I will accept it with pleasure. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew  Thank you. I revise the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the differential operator $$ P = (x^2 + 1)^3(y^2 + 1)\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right)$$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Notice that this is an elliptic operator with real-analytic coefficient.

Now define an real-analitic function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by  $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + 1)} + \frac{1}{(y^2 + 1)}.$$ Notice that Taylor series of $f$ around the origin is finite and if you compute $Pf$ you obtain a real-analytic function whose Taylor series aroung the origin have infinite radius of convergence.

We just constructed a differential operator $P$ and a function $g$ such thatt $g = Pf \in A$ but $f \notin A.$